# Why am I always getting 1 as answer irrespective of the value assigned to the variable a

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-precedence, assignment-operator, logical-and

Why am I getting 1 as output instead of 7 ( if a is initially assigned with 12 , then a-5 should give 7) or 3 as ( if a is assigned with 8 then a-5 should give 3 ). The output remains 1 always irrespective of the value assigned to a.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 12;
    if (a = 8  && (a = a - 5))
        cout << a;
    else
    {
        //do nothing !!
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignation, you want `==`  to check for equality

Comment: do you mean a==8?

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than assignment see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are trying to do but the condition in the if statement

```
if (a = 8  && (a = a - 5))
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( a = ( 8  && (a = a - 5 ) ) )
```

So the logical AND operator yields true because the left operand `8` is not equal to `0` and the right operand that represents the assignment expression `a = a - 5` also is not equal to 0. So `a` is assigned with the bool value `true` that is in the assignment ( `a = true` ) converted to `1`.

To get the expected result 3 you have to write the condition like

```
if ( ( a = 8 ) && (a = a - 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

in this example because first evaluate `8  && (a = a - 5)` which is always true and equal to 1 then it will assign to a that's why it will became 1.

if you see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) it will show that first `&&` will evaluate then `=` which is result became 1 even if you change number.

should write in this order:

```
if ((a = 8)  && (a = a - 5))
```